# Update individual element in model after translated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Is it possible to update only some elements after it were uploaded and translated into SVF file on Forge Viewer ? 
I have a project in Revit and it were uploaded to Forge Viewer, now i need to change the geometry of only some elements in Revit but not the whole model. So i need to upload to Forge the whole Revit model again just for only update some of these elements. Do you have any suggestion or better idea to deal with this situation. Thank a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the derivatives (SVF emits) are immutable and so is the extracted model data.

So that leaves us with re-translating (be sure to use x-ads-force option in the header when using the same file name) the model as our only viable option for now (you can use Design Automation to update the Revit files but you will still need to translate the model again).

Will come back to update this answer once there’s other options available.

Comment: Thank Bryan, Can we use something like Revit API to upload the Model  directly from Revit to Forge  again , not via Web service ?

Comment: If you by Web service you meant your own backend then it's possible since Forge is 100% RESTful so you can talk to it in HTTP which is supported by the Revit API. But if you meant Forge services then no - it has no deployment options so you will need to talk its RESTful services on the cloud.