# Is it possible to add custom properties to a translated SVF2 file via API or at Runtime in Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit-api, bim

When using a translated SVF from a Revit file upload to ACC, is it possible to add properties to the model elements that are not originally included in the Revit file and make those available to the Forge viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APS does not allow users to modify their SVF or SVF2 models once they are translated for the APS Viewer. This is because the Viewer is read-only and therefore developers have to do any customizations or modifications on their Revit model before they begin the translation process to SVF.

I found a similar question to yours from a developer asking a similar question: [Update individual element in model after translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652756/update-individual-element-in-model-after-translated)